# how to pass cloudwatch logs to lambda in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created two lambda functions. now i wanted to pass all the cloudwatch logs from first lambda to second lambda. i have created new log group name and subscription filter to pass the cloudwatch logs to second lambda.

I am not sure if this configuration needs to be added any resource.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "audit-logs" {
  filename         = var.audit_filename
  function_name    = var.audit_function
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(var.audit_filename)
  role             = module.lambda_role.arn
  handler          = "cloudwatch.lambda_handler"
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  timeout          = 200
  description      = "audit logs"
  depends_on       = [module.lambda_role, module.security_group]
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "splunk_cloudwatch_loggroup" {
  name = "/aws/lambda/audit_logs"
}


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_for_splunk" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.splunk-logs.arn
  principal     = "logs.amazonaws.com" #"logs.region.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.splunk_cloudwatch_loggroup.arn}:*"
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "splunk_cloudwatch_trigger" {
  depends_on      = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_cloudwatch_for_splunk]
  destination_arn = aws_lambda_function.splunk-logs.arn
  filter_pattern  = ""
  log_group_name  = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.splunk_cloudwatch_loggroup.name
  name            = "splunk_filter"
}

# splunk logs lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_function" "splunk-logs" {
  filename         = var.splunk_filename
  function_name    = var.splunk_function
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(var.splunk_filename)
  role             = module.lambda_role.arn
  handler          = "${var.splunk_handler}.handler"
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  timeout          = 200
  description      = "audit logs"
  depends_on       = [module.lambda_role, module.security_group]
}
```

how can i pass all the logs from first lambda to newly created log group ? any help ?

Comment: I would like to understand why if that is fine.

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the current code. Any errors?